# I don't manage to copy a string in c

Tags: c, string, copy

I don't manage to copy a string in my function. Once I try to print the strings, nothing appears.

```
int read_exit_tr (){
 char * buff = (char *) malloc (20 * sizeof(char));
 //char * temp;
 int r = read(0,buff,SIZE_LECTURE);
//temp = (char *) malloc (strlen(buff) + 1 );
//memcpy(buff,temp,20);
if (r > 0) {
  printf("%s X\n",buff);
//printf("%s X\n",temp);
}else
  printf("erreur");

 free(buff);
// free(temp);
 return 0;

}
```

In this version, buff is printed correctly. But once I uncomment the lines and print buff and temp, both are empty.
Thanks for reading, could you please help me?

Comment: Because you don't put anything in `temp`. You copy from `temp` to `buff`, but should be the other way.

Comment: `read()` doesn't add a null terminator, you can't use functions like `strlen()` with it.

Comment: What is `SIZE_LECTURE`? Can it be more than 20?

Comment: i used memcpy on it, I tried using strcpy too but it still dosen't work.

Comment: Just because you allocate a block of memory does not mean you are also *initializing* that block of memory.

Comment: @Yasten Your `memcpy` is opposite direction.

Comment: @Barmar SIZE_LECTURE is 20

Comment: Instead of `malloc (20 * sizeof(char))` use `calloc (21,  sizeof(char))`, this will initialize the memory to 0 and thus your string will be NUL terminated. The 21 is for makeing room for the NUL terminator

Comment: Then why not use `malloc(SIZE_LECTURE)`?

Comment: Thank you @EugeneSh. I didn't see it was opposite ^^'